# У меня есть JSON, как мне из него переделать в массив обьектов?

Tags: javascript

```
{
  user: ['jim', 'bim', 'jack'],
  name: ['one', 'two', 'thre']
}
```

вот в это:

```
[
  {
    user: 'jim', 
    name: 'one'
  },
{
    user: 'bim', 
    name: 'two'
  },
{
    user: 'jack', 
    name: 'thre'
  },
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант без привязки к именам и количеству ключей (если это усложнение будет оправдано):

```js
const users1 = {
  user: ['jim', 'bim', 'jack'],
  name: ['one', 'two', 'thre'],
};

const entries = Object.entries(users1);

const users2 = Array.from(
  { length: entries[0][1].length },
  (_, index) => {
    const user = {};
    for (const [key, values] of entries) {
      user[key] = values[index];
    }
    return user;
  }
);

console.log(users2);
```

Answer (score 3):

способов много но предложу как-то так

```js
let users = {
  user: ['jim', 'bim', 'jack'],
  name: ['one', 'two', 'thre']
}

let result = users.user.map((item, index)=> ({user: item, name: users.name[index]}));

console.log(result)
```

Comment: А если параметр вместо item назвать user, можно сразу писать `=> ({ user, name: ... }`

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Как я написал вариантов много. Я могу и не так поизвращяться. Только вот зачем.

Comment: Огромное спасибо)))

Comment: @Madrid если ответ помог то можете пометить как полезный